# Cannot find any router. Angular 8 TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Estaba desarrollando una App en Angular 8 usando Ionic como framework y TypeScript como lenguaje de Script.

Hace solo poco mas de un mes que he empezado a desarrollaar en Angular por motivos laborales, de ahi me dedicaba a desarrollar en Android, asi que estoy un poco verde aun.

Mi error seguramente venga por desacocimiento de como funciona Angular, ya que esta relacionado con el componente de navigacion entre componenetes Router.

Este lo implemento en un componente tabs, que representa al componente padre del cada tab individual.

El error que me vierte la consola del navegador es el siguiente:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/tab1'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/tab1'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2628)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2622)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:27)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at TakeLastSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28540)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
```

app-routing-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

tabs-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CaptureModule } from '../capture/capture.module';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: () => import('../login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('../home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'account',
        loadChildren: () => import('../account/account.module').then(m => m.AccountModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'capture',
        loadChildren: () => import('../capture/capture.module').then(m => m.CaptureModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('../home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'journal',
        loadChildren: () => import('../journal/journal.module').then(m => m.JournalModule)
      },
      {  
        path: 'first-screen',
        loadChildren: () => import('../first-screen/first-screen.module').then(m => m.FirstScreenModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/firt-screen',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/firts-screen',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

Si teneis idea de por donde van los tiros muchas gracias de ante mano!.

[EDIT]

He cambiado la estructura de carpetas para organizar los componentes hijos de la siguiente manera, y obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logcat:

```
ng] Error: src/app/app.module.ts:10:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './first-screen/first-screen.component' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 10 import { FirstScreenComponent } from './first-screen/first-screen.component';
[ng]                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: src/app/app.module.ts:11:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './home/home.page' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 11 import { HomePage } from './home/home.page';
[ng]                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: src/app/app.module.ts:12:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './journal/journal.page' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 12 import { JournalPage } from './journal/journal.page';
[ng]                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: src/app/app.module.ts:13:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './login/login.page' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 13 import { LoginPage } from './login/login.page';
[ng]                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: src/app/app.module.ts:9:43 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './explore-container/explore-container.component' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 9 import { ExploreContainerComponent } from './explore-container/explore-container.component';
[ng]                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: ./src/app/app.module.ts
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './explore-container/explore-container.component' in 'D:\Angular_Proyects\Ionic_Birland\src\app'
[ng] Error: ./src/app/app.module.ts
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './first-screen/first-screen.component' in 'D:\Angular_Proyects\Ionic_Birland\src\app'
[ng] Error: ./src/app/app.module.ts
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './home/home.page' in 'D:\Angular_Proyects\Ionic_Birland\src\app'
[ng] Error: ./src/app/app.module.ts
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './journal/journal.page' in 'D:\Angular_Proyects\Ionic_Birland\src\app'
[ng] Error: ./src/app/app.module.ts
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './login/login.page' in 'D:\Angular_Proyects\Ionic_Birland\src\app
```

[EDIT]

Añado la clase LoginRoutingModule, y la App al compilarla en el broswer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado el archivo login.module.ts

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginPage } from './login.page';
import { ExploreContainerComponentModule } from '../explore-container/explore-container.module';

import { LoginRoutingModule } from './login.rounting.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ExploreContainerComponentModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: LoginPage }]),
    LoginRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [LoginPage]
})
export class LoginModule{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es claro `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/tab1'`. Indica que `tabs/tab1` no se encontró. Si te fijas en el arreglo de rutas sí existe el path `tabs` pero ninguno de sus hijos tiene el path `tab1` así que de ahí el error.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: () => import('../login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
      },
      // ... resto de rutas
     ] 
  }
];
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!! Otro duda sería como debería configurar el archivo module.ts de cada componente??

Comment: Puedes explicarte más?

Comment: A ver por lo que llevo visto la comunicacione el Router lo hace a partir del componente tabs, que es el padre del resto de los componente, por lo que es en este donde le configuras las rutas a los diferentes componentes hijos, mi pregunta es: En los archivos login.module.ts y login.rounting.module.ts que tedría que programar para que la navegación se diera correctamente??

Comment: Me parece que no es  ni siquiera necesario crear estos archivos en los componentes hijos, sino solo en el padre, no?

Comment: En el `login.routing.module` solo va una ruta sencilla: `{ path: '', component: LoginComponent }` que hace referencia al componente que se va a cargar y el `login.module` importa a `login.routing.module`. Se hace así por cada componente para habilitar el `lazy loading` para que la aplicación inicie lo más rápido posible.

Comment: Vale, lo he puesto asi, pero al lanzar la App, veo una pantalla en blanco, aunque no aparece nngun errro en el logcat, ni el la consola del navegador

Comment: En el `login.routing.module` agregaste  `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` en el arreglo de imports? y luego agregaste `RouterModule` al arreglo de exports? https://gist.github.com/crrlos/6dd4bbb7039264ac98679021822f2ffa

Comment: Si, si que lo agrege, he editado el post añadiendo una captura

Comment: El problema esq aunque la app compila sin errores se ve una pantalla en blanco, como si no cargara ningun componente.

Comment: Y luego importaste `login.routing.module` en `login.module`?

Comment: efectivamente, asi lo hice, y sale la pantalla en blanco

Comment: Pero el código que agregaste es del `AccountModule`

Comment: nono, es el LoginModule solo que es una errata al copiar el codigo